# evil-vimish-fold based on syntax

Tags: evil, code-folding

[image]

`evil-vimish-fold` is really great for custom folds. However it's not clear to me how you would accomplish syntax based folds.

Does `evil-vimish-fold` work with `JavaScript mode`? Can I set `evil-vimish-fold`'s `foldmethod`

The following is what I would do in vim `ftplugin/javascript.vim`

```
syntax region foldBraces start=/{/ end=/}/ transparent fold keepend extend
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
setlocal foldlevel=99
```

Comment: In addition to asking this forum to invent a new feature, you may wish to consider opening an issue on Github as a "feature request".  The author of this library created it not too long ago -- it is still in its infancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer does not address `evil-vimish-mode`.  Instead, if
you're agnostic about which particular package does the folding
for you, you can try the built-in Hideshow mode
([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html),
[wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow)).

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html):

> Hideshow mode is a buffer-local minor mode that allows you to
>   selectively display portions of a program, which are referred to
>   as blocks. Type M-x hs-minor-mode to toggle this minor mode (see
>   Minor Modes).
>
> When you use Hideshow mode to hide a block, the block disappears
>   from the screen, to be replaced by an ellipsis (three periods in a
>   row). Just what constitutes a block depends on the major mode. In
>   C mode and related modes, blocks are delimited by braces...

You can enable it with:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode)
```

It's got some odd default keybindings (`C-c @ ...`), so you'll
probably want to rebind them to something more comfortable.

Here's an old blog post from
[Emacs-Fu](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2008/12/showing-and-hiding-blocks-of-code.html)
that describes Hideshow.  For an example with JavaScript, see
[this old blog post](http://blog.deadpansincerity.com/2011/05/setting-up-emacs-as-a-javascript-editing-environment-for-fun-and-profit/)
where it discusses "Code Folding."

Comment: I kind of wish manual folding and `hideshow` were rolled into one. But this minor mode totally gets the job done. Thanks.